# Problem in opening ".srt" (SubTitle) files in Nemo file manager

Tags: nemo

When I'm trying to open a `.srt` file, this will happen!

Before:
[image: Before]

After:
[image: After]

This doesn't happen in other file managers (nautilus and dolphin), ONLY in **nemo**! It happens for any type of `.srt`. But I can try `Open With >` and select proper software to open it. After some digging, I noticed something like this happened to text files too, I can't open them. Actually, I think or maybe other files have same situations. But for now, I just know I have to change their permissions from `-rwxrwxrwx` to `-rw-r--r--` and I can't do that! So the thing is, these creepy files that they don't want to open are located in my second Disk (HDD). I can only open it with `ldmtool` because this disk was connected to a Windows 10 for 4 years and its format is Dynamic Disk! So how can I give myself permission? I mean, It's not only this `.srt` and happened to others files too, since I don't have any other disks here to change this HDD disk to basic instead of Dynamic. Is there any way? How can open these files on **nemo** like **nautilus** without problem?

My default settings:
[image]

my file system (*all things works here*):
[image]

**changeless**: even on **root**!
[image]

Comment: You did something strange to your system. Rather than opening an editor, you associated a who-knows-what process to open text files. Right-click a file, then under Properties - Open With assign your editor to open the file by default.

Comment: I did 
"Right-click a file, then under Properties - Open With assign your editor to open the file by default."